# APCS: Signed Bits

Tags: java, integer, range

> In Java, a variable of type int is represented internally as a 32-bit signed integer.     Suppose that one bit stores the sign, and the other 31 bits store the magnitude of the number  in base 2. In this scheme, what is the largest value that can be stores as type `int`?

The answer is `(2^31)-1`. I am curious to what the purpose of the `-1` is? Why does `1` have to be subtracted from the magnitude of the number? I don't believe the `1` has anything to do with the sign because that is what the 32nd bit is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting the `0`.

In a decimal system, with a singe digit you are able to store `10` values and largest value is `9` (which is `10^1 - 1`).

This is the same story. With a `i` digits number in base `b` you are able to store `b^i` values and the largest one is `b^i-1` (I'm ignoring the sign bit right now).

As a side note: the representation used by numbers in Java (as in many other implementations) is the *two's complement* which has the peculiarity of storing just a 0 (otherwise you would end up having two `0`'s: `-0` and `+0` according to the first bit for the sign). So even if the largest value is `2^31-1`, the smallest one is `-2^31`.

Comment: In the first example, why is the largest value 9?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about two's complement notation. All java integer types are signed, and all use this to represent whole numbers.  It is very nice, because you never need to subtract.